# SSIS Script Task to Check for File Script Issue

Tags: ssis

I saw another post on here and the moderator deleted my question as I answered on an old post so here I go again with a new one..

Anoop's answer, that works great and returns Boolean which is what I want to do a prescident contraint to return then expression to either send mail or continue package but I copied the code and it's saying on this line:

Dts.Variables["User::fileExists"].Value = File.Exists(fullPath);

The word "File" next to File.Exists(fullPath); is red underlined and saying "The name File does not exist in the current context."

Do I need to define it above the code and with what code would that be?

!https://openmerchantaccount.com/img/anooperrorstackoverflow.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of your script.  Specifically, in the namespace declaration section that is probably folded by default.

```
using System.IO;
```

MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

File is a static class that lives in System.IO.  Add a "using System.IO;" at the top of you .cs file.